# How to capture textarea text WITH linebreaks and send to php?

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, get

I'm trying to experiment with taking text from a textarea in a flex project and open it up in a php page. But the php isn't line breaking where it should be...

an Example of the text i'd like to bring over to php would be:

```
You: Hi there
Them: Hello
You: This is a great example
Them: I know right?
```

Here's my php:

```
<?php 

$text= $_GET['text'];

echo $text;

?>
```

Right now I came up with something like this in the actionscript...

```
var chatBox:String=chat_box.text;

navigateToURL(new URLRequest("savelog.php?text="+chatBox), '_blank');
```

I also tried something like:

```
var chatBox:String=chat_box.text.valueOf().replace("\n","<br/>");
```

and

```
var chatBox:String=chat_box.text.toString().valueOf().replace("\n","<br/>");
```

But apparently the \n isn't translating over no matter how I get the chatBox var so its not even making a `<br/>`

But, even if i did get that to work it wouldnt be ideal. Because eventually in the end I want to be able to just incorporate the pastebin API to paste this GET data and post it on there. And I don't think it would look too pretty with having `<br/>` after every line...

So my questions is, is it possible to bring this text over to php and recognize the line breaks in a way that would work well with what im eventually trying to accomplish?

edit:
I'm a little confused because `var chatBox:String=chat_box.text.toString()` actually returns the text with \n at every line break and i can see the \n on a trace statement...but when im looking in the URL text there is no \n anywhere...any ideas? because if the \n would appear the ln2br() solution might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ln2br()  its a built in function in PHP. It also handle more than jsut the \n might be usefull in your case and i dont see that your using it yet! Try it out and let me know! You also might want to check out any encoding issues.

Comment: I'm a little confused because var chatBox:String=chat_box.text.toString() actually returns the text with \n at every line break and i can see the \n on a trace statement...but when im looking in the URL text there is no \n anywhere...any ideas? because if the \n would appear this solution might work

Comment: is there another set of character where \n should be. For example a space in a url becomes %20 That or you could replace /n by another <tag> to transport it across the url and then convert it back

Comment: actually no, it just shows up in the url bar like You: Hi thereThem: Hello. This is definitely weird Dont get why in the trace it has the \n

Comment: did you try to url encode the data before sending it as url and then url decode it?